# Object expected error on node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, getstream-io

When I run the below code on node js I get warning 'no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\package.json

npm install getstream --save

Answer (score 1):

`--save` tells npm to save the installed package version and name to the `package.json` `"dependencies"` object. If you don't have a `package.json` within the directory running `npm install` using the `--save` flag you'll end up with this problem.

You'll need to call [`npm init`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) within your project directory prior to running `npm install getstream --save`. `npm init` will ask some questions about your project prior to creating the `package.json`. If you don't want to answer the init questions, you can use the `-f` flag to force default answers.